# String encryption PHP/Java

Tags: java, php, grails, encryption, mcrypt

So, for a specific project I need to be able to encrypt and decrypt Strings in the same way that are encrypted/decrypted in another PHP application. My application is a Grails app, so I will be writing code in Java. The way the Strings will be encrypted/decrypted on the PHP side is (example code, not necessarily functional):

```
<?
$input="textToBeEncrypted";

function encrypt($data, $key)
{
$cipher_alg = MCRYPT_DES;
$mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
return @mcrypt_encrypt($cipher_alg, $key, $data, $mode);
}

function decrypt($encrypted, $key)
{
$cipher_alg = MCRYPT_DES;
$mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
return @mcrypt_decrypt($cipher_alg, $key, $encrypted, $mode);
}  

$key ="testKey";
$data=$input;
$result = decrypt($data, $key);
echo ">>" . $result . "<br>\n";
?>
```

So, I would like to be able to apply the same encryption/decryption in Java (or Groovy). I have found this example code, https://github.com/stevenholder/PHP-Java-AES-Encrypt/blob/master/security.java and I understand that if I manage to find the names of the algorithm and mode in Java, it should work. Unless if I am missing something... I navigated to the Java Standard Names page for encrypting algorithms, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html, but I can't find the exact equivalent of what I have in the PHP code. Any ideas? Has any of you guys ever needed to do something similar?

Thanks,
Iraklis

Comment: You might use the OpenSSL functions. These would probably be more portable. http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php

Comment: @ConnorPeet NOte that by default OpenSSL uses it's own key derivation function (`EVP_BytesToKey`). That's not something you will find in default Java libraries either.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, however, I most likely don't have much control over what is happening on the PHP side of the integration. My goal is to try and implement the PHP side in Java. I will mention the OpenSSL functions to them though.

Answer (score 0):

The three main things to consider with encryption are the algorithm, the mode, and the padding. Those must be compatible between the encryption and decryption software for everything to work.

To start with, `AES` (`Rijndael`) is definitely recommended in favor of `DES` as the encryption algorithm. `DES` is not considered secure enough any longer. The Java code you posted a link to is using `AES`, so it definitely won't be compatible with the PHP code you are showing.

Plus, that Java code is using `ECB` for the mode which is also not recommended. `ECB` is easier since it doesn't require any handling of initialization vectors but that is also its downfall. The PHP code is using `CBC` which is recommended, although I don't see any explicit IV handling. Mcrypt will use an IV of all zeros in that instance, which isn't ideal at all.

Finally the Java code is using `PKCS5` as the padding method, whereas the PHP code uses zero-padding. Those aren't compatible. The default provider that comes with Oracle's JDK doesn't support zero padding, however [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) does (see section 5.0). That would require either using Bouncy Castle's API directly or using it as a JCE provider using one of the methods detailed at that link. The the string `"DES/CBC/ZeroByte"` should do the trick.

Of course, zero padding can be [problematic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#Zero_padding) if the data you are encrypting can end with a null byte.

I've answered a question similar to this question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233770/encryption-method-thats-implemented-for-both-php-and-java/3234287#3234287) and provided code for encrypting in Java and decrypting in PHP in the answer. Hopefully that might help you.

Comment: Hi laz, thank you so much for your answer. Of course I understand that the Java code I posted is using different algorithm, I just wanted to show the main structure of the code. As for DES over AES and CBC over EBC, I have read about DES' weaknesses, it is just that unfortunately, I have no control over the PHP part of the integration, and the developers working on it, most probably will insist on using DES. So, if I used the Java code I posted but I changed to `new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "DES");` and `Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/0");` , would the encryption/decryption be compatible?

Comment: Or there is no way of using zero-padding in Java and I would have to include the PKCS5 padding in the PHP code?

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much Laz. I will give it a try as soon as I can and I will let you know how this went.